# Change content of a div which has a non unique class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

Want to change HTML content of a div which has a certain class but problem is there are several others and they get change too.

```
<div class="x"></div>
<div id="y"><div class"x">Change this</div></div>
<div class="x"></div>
```

I'm trying

```
    function ReplaceContentInContainer(matchClass,content)
    {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),i;
    for (i in elems)
        {
        if((" "+elems[i].className+" ").indexOf(" "+matchClass+" ") > -1)
            {
            elems[i].innerHTML = content;
            }
        }
    }

window.onload = function ()
    {
    ReplaceContentInContainer("x","Success"}
```

but as you can guess it changes every class"x", so how can I limit this only to the class="x" which is nested in a div with id="y"?

Comment: Are you using jQuery, really?

Comment: That code is almost painful and does not appear to use any jQuery

Comment: Why are you iterating through a collection of every element looking for a class name when there is a native DOM function to do this for you: `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: `document.querySelector('#y .x').innerHTML = 'changed';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery

```
$("#y .x").html("changed it");
```

That is all

Comment: doesn't seem to work though but probably because I'm using this in wordpress, javascript works and I guess jquery does too since

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Loaded!');
    });

works, so I'm kinda lost here

Comment: okay this worked
    `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#x .y").html("changed it");
    });)`